# openshift is looking for 'wsgi' application, I don't want 'wsgi'

Tags: python, openshift, tornado, redhat

I don't know if you know about this website (as I can't read your mind), but `openshift` is it. It is a web-hosting website. You can use `python` or whatever for server-side.

The problem is `openshift` is looking for a `wsgi` application. But I am using `websockets` with `tornado` so I can't use `wsgi`. How does I make `openshift` not look for `wsgi`, but any type of `applicaiton`? Or does the website only support that.

The error message I am seeing is:

```
'wsgi.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'
```

I really need a server with `websockets`, I am planning on creating a multiplayer online game with `javascript` using websockets.

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: I ran a tornado app on openshift a while ago. I don't remember how exactly I had it set up, but maybe this might help: https://github.com/iScrE4m/XLeague/blob/master/app.py#L619

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your application in `app.py`. This will allow you to run whatever you want. See:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/08/running-async-web-applications-under.html

Comment: Great! Nearly everything seems to be working. It seems that when it is on openshift, the websockets don't work correctly. I am connecting to ws://foo-bar.rhcloud.com/wschat but it says unexpected response code 400

Comment: What port are you using? At one point in time you had to request on port 8000/8443. I am not sure if that is still a requirement.

Comment: I'm getting the port from the OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT: `port = int(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT', '8000'))`

Comment: Nothing happens with port 8443, but using 8000 i get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: I think your application still had to use ``OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT``, but that you had to use 8000 from outside instead of 80 when accessing it. So externally port 80 only routed HTTP, but 8000 would do WS, with connections both ending up on ``OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT`` in the gear.

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying. I tried this in the client, but now on my server I am getting a 403 forbidden error.